# How can I prevent the Ember app from being cached?

Tags: caching, ember.js, ember-cli, browser-cache

As we're developing the app, our QA (and our users) keep seeing bugs we've previously fixed. I've seen that this can be prevented by attached a uniqueId as a query param when requesting the source files, but is there any other Ember-y way of fixing this?

Comment: This isn't a matter of ember and more a matter of your browser and web server.

Comment: If you're using the cli each build is fingerprinted, if a file changed it will be reflected, the problem is probably from the server

Comment: As @Kitler said, ember-cli will prevent this issue entirely.

Comment: @jax only if you have fingerprinting on. But I found trying to turn off finger printing for certain directories seems flakey. Has sporadic behaviour